# "Invalid block tag" when install Django-SocialRegistration to Pinax project

Tags: django

The base social Pinax project works until I add "socialregistration" to installed apps.

```
In template /home/timothy/python-environments/pinax/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pinax/templates/default/_account_bar.html, error at line 3
Invalid block tag: 'ifopenid', expected 'else' or 'endif'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is socialregistration's openid_tags.py is overwriting pinax's copy.

See:

https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/apps/account/templatetags/openid_tags.py

versus

https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration/blob/master/socialregistration/templatetags/openid_tags.py

I'm not sure if this is the issue but you might want to flag it to either of the groups and see if they get a fix for this.

I assume socialregistration is the last app you added to your INSTALLED_APPS? Then it might have overwritten Pinax's, which has the 'ifopenid' tag.